# How to call a method through both a button and another method

Tags: java, android, methods

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inserFromFile();
}

public void addrow(View v){
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
    mLayout.addView(row);
    row.addView(et1);
}

public void insertFromFile(){
    addrow();
}
```

The addRow method execute if I click on the button, but doesn't work when its called through the insertFromFile method.

How can I change it so addRow can be called through both the button and the insertFromFile method.

Thanx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens? (Note that you're trying to call it without any arguments, which doesn't help...)

Comment: The insertfromfile method can't call the addrow method, something to do with the (View v) parm of the addrow

Comment: Well yes - `addRow` takes a `View` parameter, and you're not supplying a matching argument. In future, please make sure your question contains details of what's wrong - read http://tinyurl.com/so-list for a handy checklist.

Comment: if worked with clicked use YourButton.performClick();

Comment: Ok, thnx for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void addrow(View v){ // see it takes view as param.
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
    mLayout.addView(row);
    row.addView(et1);
}
```

Method signature is different from `addrow()` does not take view as param.

`addrow(View v)` is different from `addrow()`.

`addrow(View V)` is invoked when you click a button and you probably have `android:onClick="addRow"` in xml.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

```
public void addrow(View v){
   createRow();
}


public void createRow()
{
 TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
 EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
 mLayout.addView(row);
 row.addView(et1);
}
```

and in onCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
createRow();
```

Comment: Yes, but how can i change it so it works with both a button click and the inserfromfile method

Comment: @Uys create a function `createRow`. move the code there and call the function on button click and in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

```
The addRow method execute if I click on the button, but doesn't work when its called through the insertFromFile method.
```

well addrow method is not called as you are not calling the method with intended parameters. Infact your code must not have compiled.

Add one more method or change the existing one

```
public void addrow(){}
```